# checking version numbers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, versioning

I've got a mobile app that makes an api call. In the api call, I'm sending the version number of the app because the returned json could be a bit different depending on the api version.

So when I have app version `2.4.1` and I need to check against the current api version `2.4.4`, I everything is fine because I'm using

```
if user_version.gsub('.','').to_i < server_version.gsub('.','').to_i
 //the user version is not current, ask them to update
end
```

the problem comes in down the line when somebody releases version 2.5. With the above code, the user would have `2.4.4` which gets translated to `244` which is larger than the server side `2.5` or `25`.

How would you check this to cover these instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is included as a class in Rails
http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Version.html

much easier than writing it yourself. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the version numbers using a regex, as detailed here: [A regex for version number parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82064/a-regex-for-version-number-parsing)

This one will do: `^(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)$`

So:

```
version_regex = /^(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)$/
user_version_array = user_version.match(version_regex)[1..3].compact.map(&:to_i)
server_version_array = server_version.match(version_regex)[1..3].compact.map(&:to_i)
```

For the sake of DRYness, you might want to break this out into a helper method:

```
def parse_version(str)
  version_regex = /^(?:(\d+)\.)?(?:(\d+)\.)?(\*|\d+)$/
  str.match(version_regex)[1..3].compact.map(&:to_i)
end
```

For the example of `user_version = '2.4.4'` and `server_version = '2.5'`, that gives you the arrays:

```
user_version_array = [2,4,2]
server_version_array = [2,5]
```

You can then easily iterate over these to compare:

```
compliant_version = true
(0..2).each do |i|
  if (user_version_array[i] || 0) < (server_version_array[i] || 0)
    compliant_version = false
  end
end
```