# Regex to match version number for zero or more time

Tags: java, regex

I am writing a regex to match for following type of strings:

```
my-jar-1.2.3.5.jar
my-jar.jar 
my-jar-1.2.jar
```

With the help of 
[A regex for version number parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82064/a-regex-for-version-number-parsing)
I figured out following

```
String pat = "^my-jar(-|\\.)?(?:(\\d+)\\.)?(?:(\\d+)\\.)?(?:(\\d+)\\.)?(\\*|\\d+).jar$";
Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pat);
System.out.println("For my-jar-1.2.jar - " + patt.matcher("my-jar-1.2.jar").find());
System.out.println("For my-jar-1.2.3.5.jar - " + patt.matcher("my-jar-1.2.3.5.jar").find());
System.out.println("For my-jar.jar - " + patt.matcher("my-jar.jar").find());
```

Output is

```
For my-jar-1.2.jar - true
For my-jar-1.2.3.5.jar - true
For my-jar.jar - false
```

How do I include the last case in my regex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would there be anything wrong with the following regex:

```
^my-jar(\-\d+|\-\d+(\.\d+)*)?\.jar$
```

**Demo here:**

## Regex101

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "my-jar-1.2.3.5.jar";
    String s2 = "my-jar.jar";
    String s3 = "my-jar-1.2.jar";

    System.out.println(s1.matches("my-jar(?:\\.|\\-(\\d+.)+)jar"));
    System.out.println(s2.matches("my-jar(?:\\.|\\-(\\d+.)+)jar"));
    System.out.println(s3.matches("my-jar(?:\\.|\\-(\\d+.)+)jar"));
}
```

O/P :

true
true
true

`"my-jar(?:\\.|\\-(\\d+.)+)jar"` ==> Starts with `my-jar` followed by either a "." or a `-` and one or more sets of `<digit>.` and then `jar.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
^my-jar(-|\\.)?(?:(\\d*)\\.)?(?:(\\d*)\\.)?(?:(\\d*)\\.)?(\\*|\\d*).jar$
```

Comment: Not scalable. What if the OP wants to have version with 5 levels? i.e, 1.2.3.4.5?

Comment: @TheLostMind... Agreed

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
^my-jar(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)*)?\.jar$
```

It matches the mandatory filename, `my-jar`, and then has an optional non-capturing group, which is matched if an hyphen followed by digits comes next. Then, still inside the first optional group, there's another non capturing group that can be repeated any number of time (0-...) with a commencing dot followed by digits.

Finally, whether the optional group has been matched, or not, it ends by matching the `.jar` sequence.

[Check it out at regex101 here](https://regex101.com/r/F9cj8R/1).