# This regex isn't allowing the extra digit for some reason... why?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make it so that the following are able to fit into the regex, but I'm not able to make it work.

I'm using [js on regex101](https://regex101.com) for this.

*These should pass*

- `3`
- `3.4`
- `3.5.3`
- `2.5.*`
- `3.*`

*These should fail*

- `33.2`
- `2.`
- `3.1.2.`
- `.2`
- `3.1.2.`....

My current regex is `\d?[\.?]?`
This only approves `3`. I try going forward and use `\d?[\.?\d?]?` but it still only allows `3`.

**Edit:** `3.5` technically passes in the way that `3.` and `5` pass individually but not together. How can I make it together?

Why isn't it working on the rest of the numbers? And how do I fix it?

**Update:** Please explain how the regex does work if you manage to find it. Thank you.

Comment: May you share the JS you’re using? Does it use any flags?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No flags, and my problem is with the regex... not the JS. Is it needed?

Comment: It’s useful to share it as it may highlight something else you could be overlooking.

Comment: [Your regex](https://regex101.com/r/b5qBV9/1) matches more than just `3`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It does, but I want it to match the full numbers. For example: `3.5` matched, but it was matched like `3.` and `5`

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry, but I actually don't have any javascript code. The error is coming from regex101 directly instead of js. But I believe I'm going to be running the code with `pattern.exec(nums[i])`

Comment: @12944qwerty thanks for explaining that.

Comment: `(?:\d\.?\*?){1,3}` is my initial attempt. It matches the pattern you want, but I don't know how good it is.

Comment: Why are you putting `?` inside the brackets? You don't want to match a `?` character.

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` inside square brackets, it has no special meaning there.

Comment: @evolutionxbox :O That's close `3.2.3.` passes and I don't want multiple digits between periods (`3.32` passes)

Comment: @Barmar I'm not very experienced in regex and that's how I thought it would work. the `?` means 0 or 1 instances of the previous character

Comment: @Barmar it's not a good first attempt 

Comment: Inside `[]` is not a pattern, it's just a list of characters to match. You put `?` after that to match 0 or 1 of it.

Comment: `^\d+?(?:\.[\d*]+){0,2}(?!\.$)$` second attempt. https://regex101.com/r/Wcsr2H/1

Comment: Wow, this is closest. but `33.2` passes when it shouldn't (only one number in between)

Comment: For those exact matches `^\d(?:\.\d)?(?:\.[*\d])?$` https://regex101.com/r/gbL2tM/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Wow..... can you explain that in an answer?

Comment: Has to start with a single digit, may be followed by any number of pairs of period+singledigit, last pair may be period+asterisk: `^\d(\.\d)*(\.\*)?$`.
Instead of single digit, any number of digits (at least one): `^\d+(\.\d+)*(\.\*)?$`.

Comment: I must say that the question is not very clear, but the pattern `^\d(?:\.\d)?(?:\.[*\d])?$` matches a single digit, then optionally a dot and a single digit, then optionally a dot and an asterix or digit using a character class. To prevent partial matches, it uses an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string, and and anchor `$` to assert the end of the string.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I meant to make an answer so I can accept it. But in that answer explain it lol. But thanks!

Comment: Please see my posted answer.  It has an interactive tester.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `^(\d+\.)?(\d+\.)?(\*|\d+)$` as found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82064/a-regex-for-version-number-parsing) for version numbering regex.

If you want only a singular digit between the dots then remove the `+` symbols resulting in:

`^(\d\.)?(\d\.)?(\*|\d)$`

Comment: This regex code appears to have the same problem as I stated above. (but I want it to match the full numbers. For example: `3.5` matched, but it was matched like `3.` and `5`)

Comment: They're all still part of match 1. Yes `3.` is match 1 capturing group 1 and `5` is match 1 capturing group 2, but the regex results in a single match.

Comment: Since he doesn't need to capture the different parts, use non-capturing groups to make it clearer.

Comment: ^ `^(?:\d+\.)?(?:\d+\.)?(?:\*|\d+)$` or shortened `^(?:\d+\.){0,2}(?:\*|\d+)$` The single digit version can be further shortened to `^(?:\d\.){0,2}[*\d]$`.

Answer (score 0):

`^\d(\.\d)*(\.\*)?$`

```js
var values=[
  "3", "3.4", "3.5.3", "2.5.*", "3.*",
  "33.2", "2.", "3.1.2.", ".2", "3.1.2."
];

values.forEach(value=>
  console.log(
    value,
    value.match(/^\d(\.\d)*(\.\*)?$/)?"Pass":"Fail"
  )
);

function test() {
  var value=document.getElementById("input").value;
  document.getElementById("result").innerText=
    value.match(/^\d(\.\d)*(\.\*)?$/)?"Pass":"Fail";
}
```

```html
<input id="input" onchange="test()">
<button onclick="test()">Test</button>
<span id="result"></span>
```

Must start (`^`) with a single digit (`\d`).
May be followed by unlimited pairs of period+single digit (`(\.\d)*`) - pair: `(\.\d)`, unlimited: `*`.
May be followed by a single pair of period+asterix (`(\.\*)?`) - pair: `(\.\*)`, may(single/none): `?`.
And end: `$`.

Should you want a non-zero digit, replace all `d`s with `[1-9]`.

Should you want a number rather than a digit, add a '+' after each `d`: `^\d+(\.\d+)*(\.\*)?$`.
And without leading zeros: `^[1-9]\d*(\.[1-9]\d*)*(\.\*)?$`.

Answer (score 0):

`(?:\d\.)` -> Non capturing group, with Digit `\d` matching `0-9`. Escaped decimal matches a decimal.

`?` -> followed by a `?` which matches 0 to 1 of the preceding token...

`(?:\d\.)` -> Non capturing group, with Digit `\d` matching `0-9`. Escaped decimal matches a decimal.

`?` -> followed by a `?` which matches 0 to 1 of the preceding token...

`(?:\d)` -> Non capturing group, with Digit `\d` matching `0-9`.

`$` ends string

***NOTE:*** This will allow `0.*`, `*.0`, `0.0.*`, `0.*` and `0,0,0` where `*` = some single digit number...
If you wish to filter out zeros as null then more logic would be...

```js
let regEx = /^(?:\d\.)?(?:\*|\d\.)?(?:\*|\d)$/gm;

let el = document.getElementById('input');

el.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
  let thisVal = this.value;
  
  if(thisVal.match(regEx)){
    console.log(thisVal + " is allowed")
  }else(
    console.log(thisVal + " is NOT allowed")
  )
})
```

```html
Enter a string <input id="input">
```

Comment: 3.5.* should be allowed, but isn't with your regex

Answer (score 0):

You could match a digit followed by an optional decimal part and an optional part to match a dot followed by either an asterix or a digit.

To prevent partial matches you can use anchors to assert the start `^` and the `$` end of the string.

```
^\d(?:\.\d)?(?:\.[*\d])?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `\d` Match a digit
- `(?:\.\d)?` Optionally match a dot followed by a digit
- `(?:\.[*\d])?` Optionally match a dot and either a `*` or digit
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rWE8EM/1)