# How to extract version number from linux kernel version string or kernel directory listing

Tags: regex

For example `ls` may return string
`/boot/vmlinuz-5.9.12-100.fc32.x86_64`

want a regular expression tool to extract `5.9.12-100`

Duplicate of question but additional subject
[A regex for version number parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82064/a-regex-for-version-number-parsing)

But because of SO, I can't add my answer...

Comment: parsing linux kernel version strings

To parse version number from say "/boot/vmlinuz-15.19.12-100.fc32.x86_64"
my answer, although b/c of SO i can't do
$ echo "/boot/vmlinuz-15.19.12-100.fc32.x86_64" | \
   sed -e 's/\(^[^0-9]*\-\)\([^a-z]*\)\(.*\)/\2/g' -e 's/\.\s*$//g'
15.19.12-100

Answer (score 4):

One solution using `uname`:

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-70-generic
$ uname -r | sed -re 's/(^[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*-[0-9]*)(.*)/\1/'
5.4.0-70
```

Another one using `ls`:

```
$ ls -1 /boot/vmlinuz* | sed -re 's/(^[a-z/]*-)([0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.[0-9]*-[0-9]*)(.*$)/\2/'
5.4.0-67
5.4.0-70
```